# Hi all, The matrix ee extension returns only one row

Tags: matrix

Ok here is the tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no"}
    {download_listing  sort="desc"}
          <ul>
            <p>
              <button data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn-small pull-left" onclick="location.href='#';">{title} </button>
            </p>
            <div class="modal" id="myModal">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{row_id} {row_count} of {total_rows}: {title} </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body"> <img src="{listing_image}" alt="" class="pull-left">
                    <p>{row_id} {listing_describtion} </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a> <a href="{listing_doc}" target=“_blank” class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</a> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
    {/download_listing}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and here is the link:

http://boardmans.happytesting.co.uk/download

Sa you can see i am getting the name on each buttons correct but when you click on each button the data inside; i mean the second title; listing_image and listing_describtion tags are being repeated.
Could anyone help here because it doesn't make any sense for me any more..
Thank you
Regards

Comment: Check your markup. You are using <ul> elements but they have no <li> elements inside. Then prefix each column name with download_listing. For example {download_listing:listing_image}

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem isn't with Matrix but to do with your IDs. Your hrefs are all linking to #myModal, which in itself isn't an issue, however you have 4 divs with an ID of myModal so it is always linking to the first instance. Try adding the row_id to the end of these IDs, both the div ID and button href, I think this should sort you out.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest!